# Simulation Study Calling Function

Tags: r, function, loops, simulation

I spend multiple hours of thinking about the following problem. I am running a simulation study and I want to define functions outside the simulation study in order to be able to call these functions in the end of my code.

This example illustrates the problem, but is not replicable (below you will find a replicable example of the problem). I make use of the "metafor" package for doing a meta-analysis.

I would like to use the following function that I define outside my final simulation code:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 3)

funtr.stu <- function(i) {
  for (y in 1:8) {
    mat[y,i] <- tr[[y]]$k0
  }
  return(mat)
}
```

"tr" is a list and consists of the results of 8 times an analysis. I want to retrieve the object "k0" from that list and store it into the matrix "mat".

In the following part of the code (in which I run the simulation), I want to call the function and fill the matrix "mat" with the correct numbers.

```
for (i in 1:iterations) { 
   tr.stu <- funtr.stu()
}
```

The result of this code is a filled matrix, but within each column the same numbers. Thus, R isn´t storing the numbers every iteration, but stores only the last iteration.

How can I modify my code in such a way that R is storing the output as I want?

A very simplified example:

Mat represents just a matrix with numbers and res is an empty matrix that I want to fill.

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
```

I use the function "fun" to fill the empty matrix res.

```
fun <- function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    res[y,i] <- mat[y,i]
  }
  return(res)
}
```

This is what I would like to put in the end of my code (I just want to call the function and with this function I want to fill the matrix "res"). However, if I use the code below R only fills the third row and not the first and second row.

```
for (y in 1:3) {
  test <- fun()
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case. Basically, return one row in each iteration of the for loop. Where as you are returning the entire 'res' matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
res <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)


fun <- function() {
  for (i in 1:2) {
    res[y,i] <- mat[y,i]
  }
  return(res[y,])
}

for (y in 1:3) {
  test[y,] <- fun()
}
```